# Tensorflow equivalent of the Keras function: UpSampling2D

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, keras, convolution, deconvolution

I would like to use the Keras layer:

```
from keras.layers.convolutional import UpSampling2D
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
```

How can I replicate this behavior with native tensorflow ?

I can't manage to find an equivalent function/layer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming `x` is of shape `(BATCH_SIZE, H, W, C)`, you can use `tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor`, which is the backend implementation used by keras:

```
x = tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor(x, (2*H,2*W))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D. I'm not exactly sure, but I think the tf.image functions are implemented on the CPU only.